# Как упорядочить изображения по дате?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$directory = "../content/uploads"; // Папка с изображениями
$allowed_types = array(
    "jpg",
    "png",
    "gif"
); //разрешеные типы изображений
$file_parts = array();
$ext = "";
$title = "";
$i = 0;

//пробуем открыть папку
$dir_handle = @opendir($directory) or die("Ошибка при открытии папки !!!");
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) //поиск по файлам

{
    if ($file == "." || $file == "..") continue; //пропустить ссылки на другие папки
    $file_parts = explode(".", $file); //разделить имя файла и поместить его в массив
    $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts)); //последний элеменет - это расширение


    if (in_array($ext, $allowed_types))
    {
        echo '

    <div class = "blok_img" >
    <div class="w3-container w3-third">
        <img src="' . $directory . '/' . $file . '" style="cursor:pointer" 
        onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity pimg">
      </div>
     </div>';
        $i++;
    }
}
closedir($dir_handle); //закрыть папку

?>
```

Делаю галерею на сайте, которая выводит все изображения из папки.  Как упорядочить изображения по дате, чтобы сначала были новые изображения?

Comment: Если дата для сортировки является датой создания файла, то вы можете использовать [filectime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.filectime.php) функцию для её получения, ну и сортировки в нужном вам порядке. Читаете все файлы в директории, затем сортируете, а уже после работаете и выводите HTML на основе отсортированного массива. Пример сортировки файлов в директории есть в этой ссылке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если дата для сортировки является датой создания файла, то вы можете использовать [filectime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.filectime.php) функцию для её получения, ну и сортировки в нужном вам порядке. Читаете все файлы в директории, затем сортируете, а уже после работаете и выводите HTML на основе отсортированного массива. Пример сортировки файлов в директории есть в этой ссылке.

Comment: Сделал сортировку, но почему-то во всех файлов выводит дату
january 01 1970 01:00:00.
18389 days, 6 hours, 23 minutes, 6 seconds

Но на хостинге все ок с датой. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Рекомендую либо изменить код у вашего вопроса на проблемный, либо (что будет правильнее) создать новый с ним.